# response.redirect doesnt work

Tags: c#, asp.net

When control reaches response.redirect line then the following error is produced in browser.
the url in response.redirect is correct.
The page isn't redirecting properly

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

```
*   This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept
      cookies.
```

here is the code

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

public partial class MasterPage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{    
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void imgbtnLogin_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
   {
        UserFunction objUser = new UserFunction();
        UserProperties objUserProperties = new UserProperties();
        IUserFunction iUserFunction = (IUserFunction)objUser;
        objUserProperties.UserName = txtUserName.Text;
        objUserProperties.Password = txtPassword.Text;
        string userName = txtUserName.Text; ;
        string password = txtPassword.Text; ;
        DateTime login = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime? logout = null;
        int UserId;
        string StartUpPage;
        bool success = iUserFunction.ValidateUser(objUserProperties, out StartUpPage);
        if (success)
        {
            Session["UserId"] = objUserProperties.UserId;
            Session["RoleId"] = objUserProperties.RoleId;
            Session["UserName"] = objUserProperties.UserName;
            Session["MyTheme"] = objUserProperties.Theme;
            iUserFunction.AddLoginHistory(objUserProperties.UserId, login, logout, 1);
            Response.Redirect(StartUpPage);

        }
        else
        {
            Label1.Text = "Wrong UserName/password.";
            //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "ClientScript", "alert('Invalid Credential');", true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens in IE and in Fiddler?

Comment: in IE it takes forever. and nothing happens..

Comment: If you change Response.Redirect(StartUpPage); to Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com"); do the same thing happen?

Comment: @Arkain,,, it does open google.com when i change Response.Redirect(StartUpPage); to Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com");

Comment: @Jaspal, then it appears that it is, like others have suggested, because an infinite redirect loop appears. Are you redirecting to the same page. Try to put a break point on the page you are redirecting to, and on any Redirect-call you might have in other pages.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be that you are redirecting to an endless loop?  [Here is a link](http://kb.mozillazine.org/The_page_is_not_redirecting_properly) to some info for that error.

If you had code like below for the two pages this could happen.

Page1.aspx.cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Response.Redirect(Page2Url);
}
```

Page2.aspx.cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Response.Redirect(Page1Url);
}
```

**UPDATE**

If you are positive it's not an infinite loop in your code I would follow the steps in [this link](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Websites+say+cookies+are+blocked) and see if the issues is caused by cookies.

Comment: no that is not the case. all settings correct as mentioned in info

Comment: actually i m redirecting on my login page after checking the credentials to the homepage of user

Comment: Hmm are you sure the user is authenticated?

Comment: yes if the credentials are correct then only control goes to response.redirect

Comment: Also, can you post the code from your page load even on the login page?

Comment: this is the login page mate... page load is empty

Comment: Do you have an `authentication` node in your web.config?

Answer (score 1):

You are redirecting to the same page, causing an infinite loop.